# Autodesk: How can I add units to CalibrationPanels.js of Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working in an app that use Autodesk Forge Viewer, which has its own calibration panel to do measurements in 2D plans (like PDF or DWG files).
This panel (by default) only displays these 5 units ('ft and fractional in', 'ft and decimal in', 'meters', 'centimeters' and 'millimeters')

I attach an image of the calibration panel of Forge Viewer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmSxf.png

I know that these units are declared in the CalibrationPanels.js of Autodesk libraries

Image from Forge component code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMTeS.png

But the question is... how can I change the unit list to display another units, for example, to add new units or to remove the default ones?

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the list of units is not possible currently. If you need another common unit, feel free to suggest it here and we would pass it along to the viewer engineering team.

Comment: The reason I want to customize the list of units is because in the app we're developing, we're not going to allow users to select the units "ft and fractional in" and "ft and decimal in", so we wanted to remove them from the list. But thanks anyway for the reply, Petr.